# How to skip a prompt and proceed to the next without breaking and exiting the entire loop? Java

Tags: java, skip

So I am working on a program to allow a user to add students to the class as well as manage their grades and what not. When a user selects the first option in the menu, he has to input an id (mandatory) but he could add a numerical score and/or a letter grade as well. Based on feedback in another post I managed to create a String variable line that reads user input, then checks whether it is "S"/"s" (to skip or not) and parses the value into double accordingly. Now building on the question, **how can I skip the prompt and proceed to the next prompt if the user decides to skip adding a score?** I have tried to use **break; but it exits the entire loop** . Is there a way to skip the question for score and proceed to the question for letter grade?

**Output:**

1) Add Students to Class
2) Remove a Student from Class 
3) Set Grades for a Student
4) Edit Grades for a Student
5) Show Class Report
6) Exit

1

Kindly input id:
Kindly input Score: (Enter s to Skip)

Kindly input Grade: (Enter s to Skip)

**Code**

```
// Prompting the user for Score (Numerical Grade)

System.out.println("Kindly input Score:    (Enter s to Skip)"); 
// reading the input into the line variable of string datatype
String line = input.nextLine(); 
// checking if line =="s" or =="S" to skip, otherwise
// the value is parsed into a double
if("s".equals(line) || "S".equals(line))
{
break;  // this exists the loop. How can I just skip this requirement 
        //and go to the next prompt?
}else try
{
       score = Double.parseDouble(line);                
       System.out.println(score);
} catch( NumberFormatException nfe)
{

}
// Prompting the user for Numerical Grade
System.out.println("Kindly input Grade:    (Enter s to Skip)");
String line2 = input.nextLine();
if("s".equals(line2) || "S".equals(line2))
{
       break;  // this exists the loop. How can I just skip this 
       // requirement and go to the next prompt?
}else try
{
     score = Double.parseDouble(line2);
     System.out.println(score);
} catch( NumberFormatException nfe)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `break`:

```
if("s".equals(line) || "S".equals(line))
{
  // Don't need anything here.
}else {
  try
  {
       score = Double.parseDouble(line);                
       System.out.println(score);
  } catch( NumberFormatException nfe)
  {
  }
}
```

But it is better not to have an empty `true` case (or, rather, it is unnecessary):

```
if (!"s".equals(line) && !"S".equals(line)) {
  try {
    // ...
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {}
}
```

You can also use `String.equalsIgnoreCase` to avoid needing to test `"s"` and `"S"`.

Comment: Demorgan's Law in action :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `continue` keyword. `break` will exit the entire loop while `continue` just skips the next thing.

Comment: This isn't correct. `continue` skips the rest of the loop body, whereas OP wants to go to the next prompt, which is also in the loop body.

Comment: My bad. In this case, sounds like he's better just doing `if (!"s".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) { //try statement here }`